# How to add external library to Hadoop map-reduce task

Tags: java, hadoop, command-line, jar, mapreduce

I have MyClass.java to define the map-reduce task. MyClass.java contains the definition of mapper, reducer and main. It works properly, but if I try to use/add an external jar, I have the message ClassNotFoundException.

To compile I use the command:

```
javac -classpath hadoop_library_path:my_library_path -sourcepath code_path/ -d class_path/ path/MyClass.java
```

I create the jar, and then I run the task:

```
hadoop jar maclass.jar MyClass input output -target target
```

The external jar need to be added also in in "jar hadoop" command? 
I tried with the -libjars option with no result. Any idea?

Comment: I don't know how to do it with command line (unless you have maven). One option is to use an IDE and generate a runnable jar, and another is to use maven with a maven plugin (e.g. shade) that creates an uber-jar. The latter works fine without an IDE, from command line.

Comment: I tried to create a runnable jar with NetBeans, but the error is the same.

Comment: I know that it works with Eclipse for sure, but I didn't know for NetBeans. I would recommend maven in any case.

Comment: I just use it as editor and to compile, in order to avoid command line.

Comment: As @vefthym has suggested, you will have to use Maven to create a uber jar so that external jar is included in it. Or you will have to use a DistributedCache . https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, I see two options (there could be more):

1. Use Eclipse and generate a runnable jar (I am not sure about NetBeans or IntelliJ).
2. Use maven and its shade plugin to generate an uber jar. You should add all the external libraries that you use as dependencies.

I recommend the latter option.

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: @mary any luck with this?